# Usage of sudo in a shell script

Tags: shell, sudo

When executing a shell script, how does `sudo` come into play in the following?

```
# script.sh
ls /root
sudo ls /root
```

Now, if I run `$ sudo ./script.sh` or `$ ./script.sh` what will be the difference? For example:

1. Do all commands that are run with `sudo ./script.sh` automatically prepend a "sudo" to that command?
2. Is the `sudo ls /root` line vlid? Or should the line instead of `ls /root` and require root invocation?

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the difference in a line-item being run as sudo, or the script itself being run as sudo.

Comment: Just run both and see the difference? It's really unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Within a script, before a command that requires elevated privilege, you check the `UID` (and or `EUID`) of the current user. If it isn't `0` and `root` privileges are needed, then you can use `sudo` to execute the command (or start a separate subshell if more than a simple command is involved). E.g. `if [ "$UID" -ne 0 -a "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then # use sudo` If you have a certain user that should be able to `sudo` without a password -- add that user to the `wheel` group and, as root, run `visudo` and configure (uncomment) the desired line at the end.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks -- want to put that in an answer and I can accept?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute and I'll write it up.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a script that requires elevated privileges for certain commands, one way to handle those commands is with `sudo`. Before using `sudo`, there are several considerations for configuring its use. For instance, if you have certain users you want to be able to run commands with `sudo` and further to run `sudo` without being prompted for a password, you need a bit of configuration first. `sudo` is configured through the `visudo` utility. For most uses of `sudo` you will simply need to uncomment options at the end of the file. However to allow users to run `sudo` without a password, you will also need to add those users to the `wheel` group (some distros now use a `sudo` group -- check). After adding users to the wheel group, to allow them to use `sudo` without a password, you would run `visudo` and uncomment the following line:

```
## Same thing without a password
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

With `sudo` configured, then within a script, if elevated (root) privileges are needed you simply need to check whether the user `UID` (and/or `EUID`) are equal to zero indicating the user is root, if not, then you use `sudo` to run the command. You can structure the test in the negative or in the positive to fit your taste, e.g.

```
if [ "$UID" -eq 0 -o "$EUID" -eq 0 ]; then
    command
else
    sudo command
fi
```

or

```
if [ "$UID" -ne 0 -a "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    sudo command
else
    command
fi
```

If your `command` is not a simple command, but instead contains redirections or pipelines, then you must run the entire command with `sudo` not just the first command in the list. To do so, just use `sudo bash -c "your long command"` to ensure elevated privileges are available to each part of a compound command that needs it. For example if you attempt:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers > sudoersbackup
```

The command will fail. While `cat` has the elevated privileges to read the file the `>` redirection is run as the regular user and will fail due to lack of permission. To handle that circumstance, you can do:

```
sudo bash -c "cat /etc/sudoers > sudoersbackup"
```

That ensures elevated privileges are available to the entire command.

Answer (score 0):

SUDO stands for "super user do". Basically it is a keyword that when prefixed before any other command, will force that command to run with elevated privileges. Certain commands require elevated privileges. There should be a file located at /etc/sudoers which provides a list of users or user groups who have permission to execute privileged commands.

So if your shell script requires no special privileges to run (which I expect it does not), then sudo ./script.sh should be equivalent to bash script.sh or ./script.sh.